# Unable to install solana-install-init in Docker container on Apple M1

Tags: solana-cli

Context ...some of us beta testing the **freeCodeCamp Solana Curriculum** and here is the link to the news/beta-program:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/solana-curriculum

We are running into an issue, while installing `solana-install-init` inside a docker container on Apple M1.

We have opened an issue at **freeCodeCamp/solana-curriculum** github and here is the link to it:

https://github.com/freeCodeCamp/solana-curriculum/issues/19

Docker command:

```
RUN sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/stable/install)"
```

Docker error:

```
 => ERROR [13/19] RUN sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/stable/install)"  2.5s
                                                                                
------
 > [13/19] RUN sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/stable/install)":
#0 1.529 downloading stable installer
#0 2.414 curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403 
#0 2.422 solana-install-init: command failed: downloader https://release.solana.com/stable/solana-install-init-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu /tmp/tmp.aY6AtdFPAO/solana-install-init
[2022-09-24T02:42:36.559Z] 
------
```

Answer (score 0):

To get this working you will need to download the `install` file manually and run it locally.

To do this:

- Navigate to https://release.solana.com/stable/install in your browser to download
- Save the file in your `solana-curriculum` project directory
- In `Dockerfile` replace `RUN sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/stable/install)"` with `CMD install`

Now when you try rebuild the container it will use the local `install` file and should work.